# Windows 10 Sound files can't be changed... leave us alone?

Tags: windows, audio

Unable to customize Windows sound which I totally hate since one has to be able to. I've removed editing constraints from properties, files in C:/Windows/media are now edited to my liking.

My point is this: since the machine is using the same audio files as in new Windows never mind my edits, it has to have those files stored elsewhere and turns out we're mislead when we're told the (system) sound files are in C:/Windows/media

Where are the actual files stored? I want to edit db and length, sometimes change the track completely through Adobe Audition, this  way or that, have some kind of control of the damn thing and not feel like my whole house is being a guest of Bill *ng Gates, all 365 days and then some.

Any help with that would be much appreciated and, indeed, helpful.

Please never mind time difference. It's on me

Comment: Please modify your question to exclude all rants.

Comment: Rather than trying to change system files, why don't you just change what sounds play and when with the proper system settings intended for that purpose? https://pureinfotech.com/change-notifications-sound-windows-10/

Comment: Do you have any intel on whether he's going to edit his policies of population decrease/poisoning?

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do ***is a horrible idea*** *but I will answer your question anyway*.  This is not how we modify system defaults on this operating system and you will likely break [windows side by side versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly) if you mess with the permissions here.  You WILL NEED TO mess with the permissions to edit these files.

Under the hood, these are considered windows system files even though they are only wav files.  Please don't rant about this.  It is what it is.

Specifically to answer your question, the files in `c:\Windows\Media` point to versioned folders under the `C:\Windows\WinSxS` folder (as do all of the MS files in System32).

For instance:
`C:\Windows\Media\Alarm02.wav` -> `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-shell-sounds_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_cd0389b654e71da2\Alarm02.wav`

The correct way to modify your system sounds is either by hand using the sounds control panel or if you are up to the task, editing the registry to point at other files.

Also, windows uses backslashes and not forward slashes to delimit paths.  Linux folks would tweak of I wrote `\usr\local\bin`.

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you please give me a very boiled-down risk assessment (you mentioned side-by-side versioning)? and how to STILL be able to address the editing of the wav file through permissions? A screenshot could do.

Comment: I do not have the data to give you a side by side risk assessment (nor the time or will).  In order to edit these files directly, you will need to take ownership of them and modify the ACLs for these files to accomplish this task.  WHO KNOWS what might have a problem with this (ie. windows defender? .. sfc? .. etc).  I am telling you.. this is a bad plan and not the way to get where you are going.  I get what you are trying to do.. I REALLY do, but this is not the way to get there. :)